# Access a class from multiple classes through single instance

Tags: c++, class

Below is a piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        vector<int> test;
        void push(){ test.push_back(3);}
        void display(){ cout<<test.size();}
};

class B{
    public:
        A a;
        void bar(){a.push();}
};

class C {
    public:
        A a1;
        //void set_values (int,int);
        void foo() {a1.display();}
};


int main () {
    C c;
    c.foo();
    B b;
    b.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to access push() and display() in A from multiple classes B and C. I created two objects a, a1 and accessed push and display separately. So, data pushed by a.push can't be seen by a1.display(). Can I have a common or shared object and access both methods so that the data pushed by push() can be seen by display()

Comment: Pass an instance (pointer/reference) of `A` to `B` and `C` through their constructors instead of creating new instances inside the class?

Comment: Yes, you need to learn about  *(smart) pointers* and *references* in order to do that.

Comment: Can you elaborate about your use case please? What problem do you actually want to solve? What @n.m. said, a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) seems to be suitable for that.

Comment: You are instantiating class A several times, making several separate objects. Using their methods has completely separated effects. This is one of the points of object oriented programming. Would you like to work through one or more tutorials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often if you have to use a class from multiple class, and your project requires only one instance of that particular class (ie a Display object), the right solution is to make that class a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

Here is your code modified to use A as singleton (C++ 2011 statics make the initialization of this singleton thread safe):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
        A() {}
        vector<int> test;
    public:
        static A &get() { static A a; return a; }
        void push(){ test.push_back(3);}
        void display(){ cout<<test.size();}
};

class B{
    public:
        void bar(){A::get().push();}
};

class C {
    public:
        //void set_values (int,int);
        void foo() {A::get().display();}
};


int main () {
    C c;
    c.foo();
    B b;
    b.bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use indirection. Instead of having a separate object within each class, one or both of the classes could refer to an object outside the class.

Perhaps the simplest way to achieve such *sharin*g is `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create one class which contains your data and give a reference to your second class. So both classes have direct or indirect access to the data.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:
        vector<int> test;
        void push(){ test.push_back(3);}
        void display(){ cout<<test.size()<<endl;}
};

class B{
    public:
        A a;
        void bar(){a.push();}
        void display() { a.display();}
};

class C {
    public:
        B& a1;
        C(B& _b1):a1(_b1){}

        //void set_values (int,int);
        void foo() {a1.display();}
};


int main () {
    B b;
    C c(b);
    b.bar();
    c.foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that in concrete code, it may be difficult to mange the lifetimes of C instance and the B instance that is referred to. It is easy to accidentally destroy the B while it is still needed by C.

Comment: Klaus This code works but is it possible to do without modifying the main function.

Comment: @user303661 You have to reorder foo() and bar() call to see that one element is in. And yes, you have to give the parameter. I believe you should start with a good beginner book for programming. ;) And you should also think about some guidance about software design. Cross access of data through multiple instances of classes seems broken to me.